# Meta Viewport (Fixed Width) Causing Unwanted Borders on a Transparent Image that has Background Color

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera

Note that when running all snippets below, to get a full understanding of the issue: please view on mobile-view (example, use toggle device toolbar feature from chrome developer tools).

This image is fine (not using meta viewport)

```css
.image-ok {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <img class="image-ok" src="https://i.ibb.co/mTPWBWC/shirt.png">
  </body>

</html>
```

However, when I used the code `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1440">`
**and viewed the page on mobile view** (i.e., let the meta viewport kick in)
borders on the transparent image start appearing ...

Here is the sample that produces the unwanted borders:

```css
.image-not-ok {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1440">
  </head>

  <body>
    <img class="image-not-ok" src="https://i.ibb.co/mTPWBWC/shirt.png">
  </body>

</html>
```

### Use mobile view to see the unwanted borders appearing

[image]

**Question:** Why does this happen and how can I use CSS to prevent such borders from appearing?

Note:

- Tested using Google Chrome 74.0.3729.131 and Opera 58.0.3135.132 (both mobile view)
- The issue seems to not occur on Mozilla (tested using version 66.0.5)

Comment: You shouldn't be using a fixed width in `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1440">`; you should be comparing it to the device width (with  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`). Does changing that fix the problem?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Unfortunately, I need to use that fixed width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this using the following methods:

1. I wrapped the image in a `inline-block` element
2. On that wrapper, I assigned the following CSS properties:

```
.image-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

3. On the image element, I scaled it a bit so that the borders won't appear

```
.image-ok {
    background-color: black;
    transform: scale(1.02);
}
```

---

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.image-ok {
  background-color: black;
  transform: scale(1.02);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img class="image-ok" src="https://i.ibb.co/mTPWBWC/shirt.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the viewport tag it doesn't have anything to do with it. Its something related to the rendering on the browser. The thing is the image doesn't fit to the image correctly by giving it padding like effect which causes to see a background-color. **For example, try changing the background color to white and see the more border like effects disappear.**

Comment: The border effects "disappear" when you set the background-color to white because the page itself is white.

Comment: I think its an issue in the browser rendering check when the background is transparent the same effect as white will occur

Comment: I see .. do you know how to get rid of the padding like effect that you have mentioned?

Comment: I don't know how to get rid from that.

Comment: You may try to use another strategy